# Regular expression not start with zero

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I'm using boost regular expressions for my windows app.
Here is my regular expression `folder-\\d{1,3}` this accept strings with `folder-` prefix and any **three digit** number eg: `folder-01`, `folder-001`, `folder-121`.

But now i want to avoid the numbers start from zero. eg: `folder-01`, `folder-011` and only allow numbers start from any other digit eg: `folder-1`, `folder-12`,  `folder-122`.

So How should I write change this regular expression.

Comment: Now you have one more problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to accomplish this, like so:

```
  folder-[1-9][0-9]{0,2}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
folder-[1-9][0-9]{,2}
```

Here, we are basically matching `folder-` followed by a number between **1** and **9** followed by **at most** 2 numbers.

Comment: what is the different between `folder-[1-9][0-9]{,2}` and `folder-[1-9][0-9]{0,2}`

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya There is no difference. `{,2}` is a shorthand for `{0,2}`

Comment: FYI: boost throw exception without zero {,2} `Invalid content of repeat range.  The error occured while parsing the regular expression fragment: '1-9][0-9]{>>>HERE>>>,2}'` so I think `folder-[1-9][0-9]{0,2}` is the formal one. anyway thank you so much for assist.

Comment: @NayanaAdassuriya - don't know about boost, but in C++11, `{,2}` is valid and means just what the other comments have said.